# I want to save the results of the below form directly into table present in sqlserver

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have linked R with sqserver.tried to create database and table into database through R but now  i want to save the values of below form into database .
it is receiving the values from user and want to save the result in database 
this code contains ui and server part for interface only
       library(shiny)

```
   ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Demo Interface"),

            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                textInput("text1", "STATE:",value = " "),
                textInput("text2", "REVNUE:",value =" "),
                numericInput("text3", "RATE OF GROWTH:",value = " "),
                numericInput("text4", "STATES OWN TAX",value = " "),
                numericInput("text5", "REVENUE BUOYANCY",value = " "),
                actionButton("submit1", strong("Submit"))
              ), 
              mainPanel(
                verbatimTextOutput("txt1"),
                verbatimTextOutput("txt2"),
                verbatimTextOutput("txt3"),
                verbatimTextOutput("txt4"),
                verbatimTextOutput("txt5"),
                verbatimTextOutput("txt6")

              )
            )
          )

 server <- function(input,output){

  mdata <- eventReactive(input$submit1,{
   data <- c(input$text1,input$text2,input$text3,input$text4,input$text5)
   data[is.na(data)] <- ""
   data
  })

   output$txt1 <- renderText({paste("state name is as :", mdata()[1])})
   output$txt2 <-renderText({paste("revenue is as :",  mdata()[2])})
   output$txt3 <-renderText({ paste("rate of growth :",  mdata()[3])})
   output$txt4 <-renderText({paste("state own tax :",  mdata()[4])})
   output$txt5 <-renderText({paste("revenue buoyancy :",  mdata()[5])})
   }


    shinyApp(ui, server)
    it is the interface to enter the values from user and I want to save        the results in database sqlserver
```